# How configs pick ENV value

Tags: osgi, config, aem

We have a config folder structure in apps like this:

> config
>
> config.author.test
>
> config.author.stage

These have config.runmode.env values

I wanted to know from where It picks the "env" value.

I thought it is coming from runmodes. but in the instances, stage or test is nowhere.

Can anyone please help me know where does the AEM configs picks the value or where do we define those env value. Is it in some OSGi configuration or from where.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the AEM runtime for the AEM Cloud SDK, then the [run modes](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/deploying/configuring/configure-runmodes.html?lang=en#starting-cq-with-a-specific-run-mode) can be set in other ways as well apart from the `sling.properties` file. So depending on how you are starting your AEM server check if the run modes have been specified using the other options.

If you are using the AEM runtime from the cloud SDK, then check if the Jar file is named as shown in the [Quickstart jar startup modes](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/cloud-service/local-development-environment-set-up/aem-runtime.html?lang=en#quickstart-jar-start-up-modes).

Comment: Which ever method we use, the runmodes and env name should be visible from felix console. right?